# Is there a performance benefit to narrowing the scope of a `querySelector()` search first?

Tags: javascript, performance

(If it makes any difference, I'm working on a web component.)

If I have the following:

```html
<!-- Assume a decently-sized web page with lots of elements before and after all this -->
<form>
   <input type="hidden" id="foo" name="foo" value="bar" />
</form>
<script>
let myForm = document.querySelector('form');
</script>
```

…and I want to select the hidden field, which is faster/better?

A)

```js
let field = document.querySelector('#foo');
```

B)

```js
let field = myForm.querySelector('#foo');
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) It's exceptionally likely that there is no measurable difference between the two. ID lookup tends to be *extremely* optimised by the browsers, so I don't really expect either of the two lines is "better" for performance.

Comment: I would think B is faster because there's less DOM to go through. In a large website I think this would be noticeable but on any other website. This would be helpful if you broke the rule of unique IDs to help you find the right element, but other than that it would not be significantly useful.

Comment: @Samathingamajig browsers typically have a fast lookup for IDs. E.g., a map. I doubt there is any browser, even a decade old, with decent user base that will actually do a full walk through the DOM to find an ID.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of an ID selector, I think A is likely to be faster.

IDs are supposed to be unique, so the browser almost certainly has an index of all the IDs. Looking up an ID in `document` will use this index to find the element as quickly as possible.

But if you query for the ID nested in another element, it will assume that you're violating this expectation, and it will have to do an actual search within that element. This is difficult to optimize, and there's little incentive to do so since it's not a valid DOM.

It's possible that the browser will keep track of which IDs have been duplicated. If `foo` is not duplicated, B could be optimized to be equivalent to A.

So B is at best equivalent to A, but it could be worse.